# Use attribute value of an element to find related elements

Tags: jquery

I have a list of countries and a list of regions corresponding to the countries. I would like countries belonging to a particular region to be shown when the region is clicked. This involves accessing the attribute value of the region element and using it to find countries using jQuery click event.

```
<ul id="countries_list">
    <li class="d-none" region_id="x16"><a href="/">Peru</a></li>
    <li class="d-none" region_id="x8"><a href="/">Philippines</a></li>
    <li class="d-none" region_id="x8"><a href="/">Bangladesh</a></li>
</ul>                        

<ul id="region_list">
        <li region="x8"><a href="/">Eastern Asia</a></li>
        <li region="x11"><a href="/">South America</a></li>
</ul>
```

Click event handler:

```
$('#region_list').on('click', 'li', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selected_region = $(this).attr("region");
        console.log(selected_region);    //x8
        $("#countries_list li[region_id=selected_region]").removeClass('d-none');
});
```

Clicking Eastern Asia does not show countries with `region_id="x8"`, even though `console.log(selected_region)` returns `x8`.

It works when I hard code(as a test) the value using

```
$("#countries_list li[region_id='x8']").removeClass('d-none');
```

Related posts suggest using `data-foo` attribute to change the attribute value e.g. `var selected_region = $(this).data('ref');` But here I am not changing the attribute value but using it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are hard-coding a string into your query instead of the actual value. Try this instead.

```
$("#countries_list li[region_id=" + selected_region + "]").removeClass('d-none');
```

Or, if you're using ES2015 standards…

```
$(`#countries_list li[region_id=${selected_region}]`).removeClass('d-none');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#region_list').on('click', 'li', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selected_region = $(this).attr("region");
        $("#countries_list li[region_id="+selected_region+ "]").removeClass('d-none');
        console.log(selected_region);    //x8
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="countries_list">
    <li class="d-none" region_id="x16"><a href="/">Peru</a></li>
    <li class="d-none" region_id="x8"><a href="/">Philippines</a></li>
    <li class="d-none" region_id="x8"><a href="/">Bangladesh</a></li>
</ul>                        

<ul id="region_list">
        <li region="x8"><a href="/">Eastern Asia</a></li>
        <li region="x11"><a href="/">South America</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your selected_region is not string and you should concatenate it using + +

Before:

```
$("#countries_list li[region_id=selected_region]").removeClass('d-none');
```

After: `$("#countries_list li[region_id="+selected_region+ "]").removeClass('d-none');`